# Pass arguments through command line to a gradle project without a main file

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am developing a plugin for intellij and I have a gradle.build.kts file. I build the binary using "./gradlew build". I want to pass arguments while building so for example something like "./gradlew build -DbuildType="prod"". I am trying to access this value using System.getProperty("buildType") but this returns null. The project does not have a main file.

Comment: In what file are you calling `System.getProperty()`?

Comment: In a random project file. I have many file related to the plugin but there is no main file. I need to access this value in multiple files.

Comment: When you pass arguments there you are passing them to the program running the build, not the program running your app. If you give some details of how the app is built (eg is this a Kotlin app, using the Java application plugin? Maybe easiest to show the`build.gradle.kts` file), then I can suggest how to get those parameters into your app

Comment: I can't show the build.gradle.kts file but can you explain how should I modify the build.gradle.kts file so that I can use that parameter somewhere.

Comment: the argument was coming null in build.gradle.kts as well. Can you help by giving some example and to further pass that argument to project so that it can be used anywhere. Thank you for your help!! 

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of sharing values between a Gradle build file and the target program is to use the [Gradle BuildConfig plugin](https://github.com/gmazzo/gradle-buildconfig-plugin)

Here you can write the following in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.gmazzo.buildconfig") version "5.3.5"
}

buildConfig {
    buildConfigField("APP_NAME", project.name)
    buildConfigField("THE_ANSWER", 42)
}
```

And it will generate an object of constants in your project for you to access:

```
internal object BuildConfig {
    internal const val APP_NAME: String = "<project name>"
    internal const val THE_ANSWER: Int = 42
}
```